# internet explorer: semi-transparent images

Tags: css, internet-explorer, png, opacity, alpha-transparency

I have the two images below.

They are the same image, with one having a slight glow effect on the text.

They are setup as below:

`<div id="header"><a></a></div>`
withe the original image being the background for the div, and the 'glow' image being the background for the anchor tag, with `display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%;opacity: 0;`

i am the using the below jquery code

```
$('#header a').hover(
  function() {$(this).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 1000);},
  function() {$(this).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 1000);});
```

to fade the anchor image in and out on hover.

this works fine in firefox, chrome ect.
But in internet explorer the image is given a solid black background where there is transparency.

How can i fix this?

NB: I am only worried about ie7/8 not 6.

http://webspirited.com/header-reachsniper.png
http://webspirited.com/header-reachsniper-hover.png

---

**Update**
I have decided that this is simply not worth my time to do in internet explorer.

However this works perfectly in ie9, so i guess ill remove this effect for browsers less that ie9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the opacity of a transparent PNG image, you need to use the `AlphaImageLoader` filter, *even in IE8*.

**EDIT**: You also need to add the `alpha` filter in the CSS, like this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="path", sizingMethod="scale"),alpha(opacity=100);
```

Otherwise, jQUery will clear the existing filter as it adds the `alpha` filter.

Comment: loading the image using alphaImageLoader the 'hover' image shows at page load, then when you hover over the link it disappears untill you refresh the page.
How can i fix this?

Comment: @Hailwood: I forgot to mention that you need also to explicitly add the `alpha` filter in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This post from Dave Shea's [mezzoblue.com](http://mezzoblue.com) may help you: http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2010/05/20/ie8_still_fa/

It notes all of the methods which he tried, and the final solution he arrived at the end:

> What did work was a little library
>   called [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/)  that applies PNG
>   transparency via VML instead of
>   AlphaImageLoader. It’s designed for
>   IE6, but it works just fine in IE7 as
>   well. For IE8, I was forced to throw
>   out an [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(VS.85).aspx) meta tag and
>   step IE8 down to IE7 mode for this
>   particular page.

With a tiny caveat at the end

> It’s still not perfect. I noticed a
>   faint white bounding box poking
>   through at lower opacities that forced
>   me to slightly adjust hover effects
>   for all versions of IE. But you know,
>   for all that, it’s darn well good
>   enough.